# heroku rails - all commands give "No account specified"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ssh, key-generator

**[Note: this is not about using --app appName, that's a different issue]**

Due to doing both work and personal github projects my machine has got its git/heroku setting mixed up.  I'm trying to just back to defaults but can't find all the 'artifacts'.

Trying to do commands such as

```
heroku keys
heroku keys:add
heroku keys:clear
```

even trying to add my key again!

```
heroku keys:add --app blazing-planet-3592
```

are all giving me

```
durrantm.../linker$ heroku keys:clear
Removing all SSH keys... failed
 !    No account specified.
 !    
 !    Run this command with --account <account name>
 !    
 !    You can also add it as a git config attribute with:
 !      git config heroku.account work
```

I recently installed heroku account to manage multiple accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to my problems was that I needed to add `--account personal` to each command that I use in order to reference the file `~/.heroku/account/personal` (that I created when I started using heroku 'accounts' functionality) which has my info as in:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/accounts/personal
:username: m2@snap2web.com
:password: b1951...868b6
```

so my commands just need to be:

```
$ heroku keys --account personal
$ heroku keys:add --account personal
$ heroku keys:clear --account personal
$ heroku keys:add --app blazing-planet-3592 --account personal
```

I also subsequently ran heroku account:add work and then put in my WORK credentials (email & pw when prompted) for the (different) account that I use for work.

It told me to add stuff to my .ssh/config file -

Add the following to your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host heroku.work
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile /PATH/TO/PRIVATE/KEY
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

but I'm leaving that undone for now (would welcome suggestions about options for that, when it's needed, etc.).